# どこまで質問に完璧さを求めるか

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

[Range-based for loopで参照にした時としない時の速度面での違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7263/)
この質問に対し、実測しろとか条件を書けとか突っこみが入り、実際に質問修正がなされていますが、私としては最初の質問文で不十分とは感じませんでした。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/7263/revisions

この質問に対する回答では、コピーの有無という挙動の差があるので、最初の版にある情報で、「一般的には…」と答えるのには十分です。実際に、最終的にAcceptされた回答はすぐ付いていて、むしろ修正のデメリットが目につきます。

- 気軽に質問しづらい方向に雰囲気が向く
- 質問文がとても長くなり、見づらいし質問内容も一見ではわからなくなった

それでも、このような突っ込みを入れていくべきでしょうか？

完璧を求めるのであれば、「○○バイトとありますが、1バイトは何ビットのアーキテクチャですか？」と、バイト表記している質問に突っ込みを入れて回らなければなりませんが(これは馬鹿げた極論です)、どこに境界線を置くべきかという問題です。

Comment: 本件を特に取り上げたのは、回答に実行環境依存の局所性がないと考えられるためです。コピーのオーバーヘッドの有り無しなので。回答は一意であり、すぐ役に立たなくなるものでもないのでは。環境を示させることにより、何が向上したでしょうか？  
読みづらくなる件は、既にご指摘をいただいているように、どちらかというと編集・表示機能に関する問題でしたね。折りたためればいいのですが。

Answer (score 9):

それほど厳密にルールを決めなくても良いのではないでしょうか。

---

あくまで個人の考えとしてですが、スタックオーバーフローは魚をとってあげるサイトではなく、魚の釣り方を教えるサイトだと思っています。また、相互互助であってサポートではありません。そういうわけで、ベンチマークを取るように促すコメントは個人的には問題だとは思いませんでした。

どこまでの前提を質問に求めるかはおそらく人によって異なります。(私は率直に「あれ？実測してないの？」という印象を受けました。)
そこまでする必要はないだろうという意見が出るのもわかりますので、こういったテーマを考える機会があるのは良いことです。

突っ込みかどうかはさておくとして、コメントはあくまでコメントですから、受け入れられるコメントであれば参考にし、受け入れられないコメントはノイズとしてみなせば十分ではないでしょうか。ヤジや中傷の類であればモデレータの方が対処してくれます。

Answer (score 6):

私はスタックオーバーフローに定住する気はないので、スタックオーバーフローの住人の意向に沿った対応をすればいいと思いますが、一応火種になったので補足も兼ねて意見を書いておきます。

私がこの質問に対して｢成り立っていない｣と言ったのは、**速度面での質問においては**質問者様の「一般的には…」という回答は資料として価値が低いと考えているからです。

コメントに書いたとおり、速度というものはコンパイラや実行環境、アーキテクチャによって大きく左右するものであって、一概に答えられるものではありません。
単純な計算量や一般的な環境での速度は、少し経ってコンパイラのバージョンが変わったり、アーキテクチャが変わったり、そういう些細な違いで｢一般的ではなくなる｣可能性が非常に高いです。
**今現在**、一般的であると前置きするならまだしも、そういう回答をしてる人などいませんね。

このへんはdokubekoさんの回答にあるとおりです。

私は別に完璧を求めて質問にコメントしたのではなく、**少し経てば変わってしまうかもしれない"一般論"を回答したとして、その回答は永続的な価値を持つ資料なのか**、という観点からの指摘です。
｢○○は遅い｣｢○○はしてはいけない｣などという迷信は、こういうところから生まれるのだと私は考えています。質問を何年後かに見た誰かにとって、その質問に価値があるものである可能性は不明瞭です。一方、環境などを明示したのならば、それはその後でも価値のある資料になるはずです。

それと、我々は別に｢無駄にコードを要求したり｣、｢ベンチマーク結果を載せろ｣などとは言っていないことに注意してください。頓珍漢な回答をしている人がいますね。
あくまでも実測というステップを踏むべきだという提案をしているに過ぎません。

読みづらくなった、などの点はコメントの内容とは別の問題であると思います。これはほぼyohjpさんの意見のとおりです。

まあ、冒頭に前置きしたとおり、スタックオーバーフローの住人が納得するようにすればよいと思いますし、私の考えを排除したければ通報することもできるでしょう。とりあえず現状コメントで指摘をすることがルールに違反することではないようですし、意見が収束するのを傍観することにしておきます。

Answer (score 3):

その質問は、実行環境に依存する**局所性**と、誰もが同じ結果を得られる**一般性**が混在してみえます。また、**買い物リスト**のような聞き方をしています。

局所性と買い物リストの性質に注目すればコメント欄での指摘はもっともですし、一般性に注目すればベストアンサーのように答えられる内容だと思います。あなたは一般性の部分を認めて肯定していますが、他の方は局所性を問題視したのかもしれません。

コメントした方々がどのような着地点を想定したかは分かりませんが、「自身の環境を明らかにし、実測せよ」としたのは、実行環境に依存するという局所性を排除するために良いアドバイスだと思います。質問内容の一般性を高くしていけば、より多くの他のプログラマーが問題を当事者として捉えることができ、Q&Aとしての有用性が増します。

着地点としての、より良い形は、3つの実測結果と実行コードを示した上で、その速度差を生む要因について質問をし、将来的に同様の比較を行う際の背景知識が回答として出現することだと思います。

> それでも、このような突っ込みを入れていくべきでしょうか？
>   どこに境界線を置くべきか

その線引きは個人個人の考え方と時流によると思います。**誰もが質問・回答できるQ&Aサイトとしての利便性**と、**プログラミングの問題のナレッジベースとしての有用性**、そのふたつのどちらを重視しているかです。こうやってメタで討議が上がるたびにどちらかに傾き、傾きすぎれば新しく討議が上がり別の方向に傾くのではないでしょうか。

最後に、その二点についてじぶんの姿勢を記しておくと、突っ込みは入れていくべきで、その境界線は**局所的すぎる質問**の「すぎる」がとれる程度です。また、どちらかと言えばプログラミングの問題のナレッジベースとしての有用性を重視して臨んでいます。

Comment: 質問者が自分の環境で実測してみることで「局所性が排除される」のでしょうか。むしろ「実際の速度は環境によって異なる」と前置きして、一般的な部分のみに回答したほうが、一般性が高くなるのではと思うのですが。

Comment: 文中にあるように「3つの実測結果と実行コードを示した上で、『その速度差を生む要因について質問をし』」までたどり着けば、速度差の要因についての背景知識に焦点が移り、局所性が排除されていきます。

Answer (score 2):

「どこまで質問に完璧さを求めるか」については、回答に足る情報が集まる程度までと考えています。

> それでも、このような突っ込みを入れていくべきでしょうか？

むしろ、最初から完璧な質問などめったに存在しないからこそ、それが建設的な指摘である限りは、第三者コメントが機能すると考えます。なお、不適切と考えられる場合は[コメントも通報対象](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)になります。

---

> 私としては最初の質問文で不十分とは感じませんでした。
>   最初の版にある情報で、「一般的には…」と答えるのには十分です。

個人的には moccos さんと同じく、最初の質問文でも十分だと思いました。（なので、そこから読み取れた内容に関して一般論の回答をしてみました。）

> 質問文がとても長くなり、見づらいし質問内容も一見ではわからなくなった

本ケースに限れば、「本文中にどこまでのコードを提示(追記)すべきか」という問題な気がしました。性能計測に利用したコードを全て提示された副作用だと思いますが、中途半端に省略すると「全部だせ」というコメントも付く気がしますので、一般的な対応は難しいですね。本質からそれたコードは、[Gist](https://gist.github.com/)などの外部サービスを利用するという暗黙ルールでもあればよいのですが。

---

以下、完全に蛇足ですが：

> 完璧を求めるのであれば、「○○バイトとありますが、1バイトは何ビットのアーキテクチャですか？」と、バイト表記している質問に突っ込みを入れて回らなければなりませんが(これは馬鹿げた極論です)、どこに境界線を置くべきかという問題です。

必要とあらば、このような指摘もあって然るべきと思います（オクテットという単位もありますし）。結局、質問者の関心領域はどこかという話であり、ケースバイケースになってしまいますね…

Answer (score 1):

私も最初の質問の方が簡潔でわかりやすく、修正しない方が良かったと思います。
無駄にコードを要求したり長文貼り付けるのは資料としての価値を損なうので止めてほしいと思います。